Gravitational binding energy of a sphere with radially-dependent density
As stated here, the gravitational binding energy of a uniform sphere is:
$$U = \int_0^R -\frac{G}{r} \left(\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\rho\right) \left(4\pi r^2\rho\right) \mathrm{d}r.$$
I want to know if the energy for a sphere with radially-dependent density $\rho(r) = f(r)$, such as a star with density larger in the center and smaller in outer parts, has the same form:
$$U = \int_0^R -\frac{G}{r} \left(\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\rho(r)\right) \left(4\pi r^2\rho(r)\right) \mathrm{d}r.$$

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/362310/321853

Thanks @Ghoster

You need to replace $\frac43\pi r^3\rho(r)$ with $\int_0^r4\pi s^2\rho(s)ds$.
