# Gravitational Binding energy of a sphere of 2 uniform densities

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, planets, binding-energy

So I know that the gravitational binding energy of a sphere of uniform density can be given by:
$$U=-\frac{16}{3}G\pi^2\rho^2\int_0^Rr^4dr$$
Which if integrated gives:
$$U=-\frac{3GM^2}{5R}$$
As desired. But say I had a density function given by:
$$\rho(r)=\begin{cases}\rho_a&\text{ for } r\leq r_a\\\\\rho_b&\text { for } r_a<r\leq R\end{cases}$$
Could I then write that:
$$U=-\frac{16}{3}G\pi^2\int_0^R\rho(r)^2r^4dr$$
$$U=-\frac{16}{3}G\pi^2\left[\int_0^{r_a}\rho_a^2r^4dr+\int_{r_a}^R\rho_b^2r^4dr\right]$$
Or am I missing some nuance? I feel like I am because I don't think I'm taking into account the mass of the first density in the second integral, but I am honestly not sure. Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: No way that from the first formula, you can get the second one. That is the potential energy of two spheres of mass $M$ at a distance $R$. But is it relevant to your question?

Comment: Although the problem is different, this question  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/341065/gravitational-potential-energy-of-any-spherical-distribution?rq=1  could be relevant to your problem.

Comment: $U=-GM/R^2$ is incorrect. The binding energy of a uniform sphere has a factor of 3/5. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy). You should figure out your mistake before moving on to a non-uniform sphere.

Comment: @G.Smith it was just a typo my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I then write that...

No, it's more complicated than that. You didn't show how you got your first integral, but one way to do it is as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy):

Imagine that it is pulled apart by successively moving spherical shells to infinity, the outermost first, and find the total energy needed for that.

The mass $dm$ of a shell between $r$ and $r+dr$ is

$$dm_\text{shell}=\begin{cases}
4\pi r^2 \rho_a\,dr, & 0<r<r_a \\
4\pi r^2 \rho_b\,dr, & r_a<r<R
\end{cases}$$

and the mass inside this shell is

$$m_\text{interior}=\begin{cases}
\frac43 \pi r^3 \rho_a, & 0<r<r_a \\
\frac43 \pi ra^3 \rho_a + \frac43 \pi (r^3-r_a^3)\rho_b, & r_a<r<R.
\end{cases}$$

The potential energy between these is

$$dU=-G\frac{m_\text{interior}dm_\text{shell}}{r}.$$

Integrate this over the entire sphere in two parts, $0<r<r_a$ and $r_a<r<R$.